# First image not showing

Tags: php, image

I changed the html code below

```
<a href="<?php echo pietergoosen_get_first_image() ?>" title="<?php printf( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="lightbox">
          <?php echo pietergoosen_adjust_first_image(pietergoosen_get_first_image(), get_the_title(), 525, 0); ?>
       </a>
```

to the function below as I need more than one image size with an if statement

```
function pietergoosen_the_excerpt_image_output() {
$firstImage = pietergoosen_get_first_image();
$imageAttribute = esc_attr(the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ));
$title = get_the_title(); 
if (isset($classes) && $classes == 'custom-sidebar-per-page-width'){
    $imageSize = '525';
} else {
    $imageSize = '380';
};

printf(
    '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="lightbox"><pietergoosen_adjust_first_image(%1$s, %3$s, %4$d, %4$d)></a>',
        $firstImage,
        $imageAttribute,
        $title,
        $imageSize
);
 }
```

I call the function like this

```
<?php echo pietergoosen_the_excerpt_image_output(); ?>
```

but the image now does not show up anymore. Any advice on how to fix it, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your printf() call is a total mess. It's got syntax errors and is utterly unecessary:

```
echo "<a href='{$firstImage}' title='$imageAttribute' etc....";
```

is all that's necessary.

With your version:

```
printf('<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="lightbox"><p
       ^--single quoted string
                 ^^--- not a valid formatting char for printf
                   ^^--- variables are NOT interpolated in '-quoted strings
```

A proper (and still unnecessary) printf() would've been

```
printf('a href="%s" title="%s" ...., $var1, $var2);
                ^^--insert a string
```

The ONLY time a printf/sprintf() call would be useful in PHP is if you need to do special formatting on an inserted character, e.g.

```
printf('%05d', 12); // outputs 00012
```

Comment: I'm very new to php, so thank you for pointing out the use of printf() to me. You say my printf() function is unneccesary, which I now understand. In stead of using the print() function, what would you use to output thestring then.

Comment: just a normal `echo` or `print`. as long as you use `"`-quoted strings, PHP will replace any varaibles inside with their values.e.g. `$var = 'hello'; echo "$var there";` will output `hello there`. using `'` strings won't work. `echo '$var there'` will output, literally, `$var there`.

Comment: This is actually incorrect. With `%1$s`, you can repeat the placeholders as many times as you like. This is known as [**argument swapping**](http://php.net/sprintf). For example, `printf('%1$s, %1$s and %1$s!', 'hello');` [outputs](https://eval.in/101896) `hello, hello and hello!`.

Answer (score 0):

Your new function is not returning a value to echo, it is printing from within the function. The last line should be:

```
return sprintf(
    '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="lightbox"><pietergoosen_adjust_first_image(%1$s, %3$s, %4$d, %4$d)></a>',
        $firstImage,
        $imageAttribute,
        $title,
        $imageSize
);
```